# port 80 is open by iptables but Connection timed out

Tags: nginx, iptables, firewall

I have nginx on my server, I run the script below to add rules to iptables:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=/sbin/iptables
services='22 25 53 80 443 5432 8000 8080'
$ip -F;
$ip -t nat -F;

echo -e "Opening port 22 for ssh";
$ip -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT;
$ip -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT;

$ip -P INPUT DROP;
$ip -P OUTPUT ACCEPT;
$ip -P FORWARD DROP;

echo -e "Accept lo";
$ip -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT;
$ip -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT;

$ip -A INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT;
$ip -A OUTPUT -o docker0 -j ACCEPT;

# ethernet
#echo -e "Accept eth0";
#$ip -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT;
#$ip -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j ACCEPT;

for service in $services; do
echo -e "Open port $service";
$ip -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport $service -j ACCEPT;
done

$ip -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT;
$ip -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT;
$ip -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51914 -j ACCEPT;
```

I open necessary ports, but when i try to access my website using wget i get the following error:

```
--2016-01-20 14:28:33--  <ip>
Connecting to <ip>|:80... failed: Connection     timed out.
Retrying.
```

well, what is the problem of my script for firewall?

edit:
the output of `iptables -L INPUT -vn` is

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                   destination         
  218 18351 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
   29  4456 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0                    
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:22 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:25 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:53 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:80 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:443 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:5432 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8000 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:8080 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:53 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:51914
```

Comment: show is the output of `iptables -L  INPUT -v -n`

Comment: it shows that port 80 is open correctly.

Comment: No, it doesn't; see below.

Comment: Whats the output of `netstat -nlp | grep nginx` or `netstat -nlp | grep 80`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `INPUT` rule allows traffic with **source** port 80 - but traffic coming into a web server is for **destination** port 80.  You are, in essence, allowing only `INPUT` traffic *from* other webservers.  Change `--sport` to `--dport` in your rule, and all should be better.

The same point applies to nearly all your other rules, by the way.